# PHP server sends json respond to swift client shows this error

Tags: php, json, swift, apache, server

> PHP server sends json respond to swift client shows this error, knowing that the send is within a local network.

```
<?php

require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");
$Id = htmlentities($_POST["Id"]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);
$returnValue = array();

if(empty($Id) || empty($password))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

//$secure_password = md5($password);

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetailsWithPassword($Id,$password);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(!empty($userDetails))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is registered";
echo json_encode($userDetails);
} else {

$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is not found";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
}

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

> Swift error msg:"UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}"

Comment: It’s likely that the data you’re getting back isn’t JSON, or is subtly malformed JSON, what is the json output?

Comment: Your error message is from Swift, but all your code is in PHP. Not a good strategy to get an answer. Please post your Swift-code too and, given your error message: post the raw data you get in Swift (converting the `Data` to a `String` using the appropriate initialiser and providing a matching encoding). Very probably the first character you print out will be extremely helpful. Should it not be: Using `Codable` and `JSONDecoder` greatly improves the quality of error messages (in general, probably not in this case though).